# Jmeter: Can we use Jp@gc Perfmon Metrics collector Even if Firewall is ON at the server end

Tags: amazon-ec2, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

Is it possible to use Jp@gc Perfmon Metrics collector to fetch/Monitor the CPU and Memory usage if Firewall is set ON.

The application server is in Amazon ECII. So I do not think they are going to Switch off their firewall for security Reason.

Can anyone tell me he way around.

Thanks

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

start a server-agent EC2 Server where your application is hosted

> cd ${jmeter_folder}/lib/ext/
>   java -jar ./CMDRunner.jar --tool  PerfMonAgent --udp-port 0 --tcp-port 7777

**Open TCP port 7777 in the EC2 Security Groups**

Add Jp@gc Perfmon Metrics collector Listener to your test script, and configure the server IP & Port.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I have ran a Server Agent in the EC2 Server. I executed the script with Jp@gc Perfmon Metrics collector with IP address and Port 4444. As 4444 is by default port mentioned. 

What should be my next step?

1)Should I ask them to Open the port 4444 in the Server at Amazon EC2?
2)I am able to access the same Server using Puttty with IP address and Port 22. So shall I use the same in the Perfmon Metrics Collector?

Comment: no, you cannot use port 22. you have to get port 4444 opened.

Comment: I will ask them to open Port 4444 in the server. When we start the startAgentbatch file is 4444 gets opened automatically?
Even if Firewall is on I will ask them to allow 4444 in firewall?

Comment: In the EC2 --> Select particular server --> go to Security Groups --> open TCP port.

Comment: I might sound silly but query is: When we start the startAgent batch file is port 4444 is created/opened automatically. So do we need to create it again? Or am I missing any point. Fact is I do not have access to Server I need to tell my client to do so.

Comment: If the Agent is already running, there is no need to start/restart it.
you just need the open port at firewall so that your Jmeter client is able to talk to ServerAgent.